# PHPUnit returns 0 coveredmethods

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to make my PHPUnit tests working.
I want a result of the test coverage (it will be upload to a sonarqube)

The problem is, when I execute my tests, the coveredmethods still at 0...

src/Controller/DefaultController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/default', name: 'default')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'DefaultController',
        ]);
    }

#[Route('/default2', name: 'default2')]
public function test2(): Response
{
    $test = 0;

    $test++;

    echo $test;

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'DefaultController',
    ]);
}

#[Route('/default3', name: 'default3')]
public function test3(): Response
{
    $test = 0;

    $test++;

    echo $test;

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'DefaultController',
    ]);
}
}
```

tests/DefautTest.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class DefautTest extends TestCase
{

/**
 * @covers \App\Controller\DefaultController::index
 */
public function testSomething(): void
{
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

phpunit.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
     convertDeprecationsToExceptions="false"
>
<php>
    <ini name="display_errors" value="1" />
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
    <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
    <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value="" />
    <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="9.5" />
</php>

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
    <include>
        <directory suffix=".php">src/Controller</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">src/Entity</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">src/Repository</directory>
    </include>
    <report>
        <clover outputFile="result-coverage.xml"/>
        <xml outputDirectory="xml-coverage"/>
    </report>
</coverage>

<listeners>
    <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\CoverageListener"/>
</listeners>
```

And, the result-coverage.xml, with coveredmethods = 0...
It would be one; no ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage generated="1628073827">
  <project timestamp="1628073827">
    <file name="/usr/src/app/src/Controller/DefaultController.php">
      <class name="App\Controller\DefaultController" namespace="global">
        <metrics complexity="3" methods="3" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="12" coveredstatements="0" elements="15" coveredelements="0"/>
      </class>
      <line num="11" type="method" name="index" visibility="public" complexity="1" crap="2" count="0"/>
      <line num="14" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="15" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="19" type="method" name="test2" visibility="public" complexity="1" crap="2" count="0"/>
      <line num="22" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="24" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="26" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="28" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="29" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="33" type="method" name="test3" visibility="public" complexity="1" crap="2" count="0"/>
      <line num="36" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="38" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="40" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="42" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <line num="43" type="stmt" count="0"/>
      <metrics loc="46" ncloc="46" classes="1" methods="3" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="12" coveredstatements="0" elements="15" coveredelements="0"/>
    </file>
    <metrics files="1" loc="46" ncloc="46" classes="1" methods="3" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="12" coveredstatements="0" elements="15" coveredelements="0"/>
  </project>
</coverage>
```

If anyone have an idea why do I have coveredmethods = 0...

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity: why don't you properly **test** that method?

Comment: I'm creating a new project from scratch and I'm configuring all the stuff around (tests, CI, ect...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review the code, the code coverage is the representation about what code was executed with the test, now lets look the test:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class DefautTest extends TestCase
{

/**
 * @covers \App\Controller\DefaultController::index
 */
public function testSomething(): void
{
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

Basically this tests is only making an assertion of true, but not executing the code on the controller, the mark or annotation "@covers" is the representation about, what supposes to cover the test.

Try with this example:

```php
namespace App\Tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\WebTestCase;

class DefautTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testFunctional()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', '/default');
        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful(); //This method can be different of your version of phpunit
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It solves my issue